# As a business requirement, i have to keep my background service running at all times in my android application

Tags: android, alarmmanager, background-service

I have decided to ask this question after a research of almost 3 weeks.

The requirement is such that my app has only one background service and it has to search for BLE devices all the time. (Don't freak out I have set up a slow scanning mode when no BLE device is in range in which i pause and resume the scan). The app is not for everyone as it is meant to do some authentication with the BLE devices whenever one comes in range. Hopefully this establishes the IMPORTANCE of service running all the time. I can't use foreground service (business requirement).

Whenever android kills my service `onDestroy()` is not called. So my best bet is to use an Alarm Manager which triggers every 5 minutes and checks if the service is killed and if it is killed it calls `startService()`. Alarm triggers fine for some time but after random times (1, 2 3 hours) even the alarm gets killed and it doesn't trigger anymore.

I'm sending a broadcast through the alarm whose `onReceive()` is responsible for starting the service if it is killed. I'm out of workarounds can any one explain or suggest why the alarm manager malfunctions after some random time. I'm currently testing my app on nexus 6p, Galaxy s7 edge, Samsung A5, Huawei P9.

Any more explanation can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alarm triggers fine for some time but after random times (1, 2 3 hours) even the alarm gets killed and it doesn't trigger anymore.

If `adb shell dumpsys alarm` does not show your alarm, then you might say that "the alarm gets killed". That normally does not happen unless the user uses Force Stop in Settings.

However, most likely, the alarm itself is there. However, the device has gone into [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), and so your alarms will be ignored. Your options are:

- Try `setAndAllowWhileIdle()`, which may not be sent as frequently as you would like, or
- Have the user add your app to the battery optimization whitelist, bearing in mind that users may elect to not do this, or
- Have the user keep the device plugged in all the time, bearing in mind that users may elect to not do this

> I'm sending a broadcast thrugh the alarm whose onReceive() is responsible for starting the service if it is killed

Unless you are using a `WakeLock` (carefully), there is a chance that the device will fall back asleep before your service actually gets started.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll check with adb tomorrow if the alarm actually seizes to exist. How can is use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` and get the alarm to repeat every 5 minutes? And about the 'WakeLock', I acquire it in the `onReceive()` of my broadcast receiver and after calling `startService()` I release it. Isn't is how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @madking: "How can is use setAndAllowWhileIdle() and get the alarm to repeat every 5 minutes?" -- you can't. I think the advertised minimum period is 9 minutes, and it might not even be that frequent. "Isn't is how it's supposed to be?" -- that means your `WakeLock` is acquired for about a microsecond. `startService()` is asynchronous; the service is not started when `startService()` returns. I would expect your service to need a `WakeLock` to do its work anyway, which is why users may be unhappy with your app.

Comment: Plus I'm using `RTC_WAKEUP` and I have a notification issued in the `onReceive()` so regardless of whether the service is started or not or the phone is in DOZE mode (introduced in Android 6) the notification should display whenever the alarms triggers as it wakesup the CPU for a very brief moment. But the notifications stop comming after some time.

Comment: 9 minutes is okay with me but doesn't `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` triigers only once? So then maybe I should release the lock inside the service? I'm already acquiring a wakelock inside the service in a broadcast receiver which broadcasts whenever the screen state changes. The thing is user wants me to run the service all the time as it's an app for a business client

Comment: @madking: "but doesn't setAndAllowWhileIdle() triigers only once?" -- part of your work, when the alarm triggers, is to schedule the next alarm. "So then maybe I should release the lock inside the service?" -- yes, acquire it in the `BroadcastReceiver`, but release it in the `Service`. This is how `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` works. "The thing is user wants me to run the service all the time as it's an app for a business client" -- the user may have a change of heart when the user realizes how much battery your app uses.

Comment: lol it's not that bad, I have optimized the scanning process and the app does not drain insane amount of battery, One last thing please, where do I release the lock as I'm acquiring the lock inside the service too(when the screen turns off acquire the lock when the screen turns on release the lock) and there is no guarantee of `onDestroy()` being called when android kills my service. P.S I return `STICKY` too in the `onStartCommand()`  and use android:persistent in `<application>` tag of my app.

Comment: @madking: "where do I release the lock" -- when you no longer need it. I would assume you need it to do your BLE scanning, so perhaps you release it when the scan completes.

Comment: @CommonsWare , where is the other problem for Huawei devices: any process is force killing by OS.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41622804/1979882 .